# Scale of X axis in forest plot

Tags: transform, forest-plot

The question is very simple.
For the help file of the `meta` package, let's consider this forest plot:

```
data(Olkin1995)
m1 <- metabin(ev.exp, n.exp, ev.cont, n.cont,
  data = Olkin1995, subset = c(41, 47, 51, 59),
  sm = "RR", method = "I",
  studlab = paste(author, year))

forest(m1, layout = "RevMan5", common = FALSE,
  label.right = "Favours control", col.label.right = "red",
  label.left = "Favours experimental", col.label.left = "green",
  prediction = TRUE)
```

Results as follows:

[image]

Now, the question is: how the X-axis of the forest plot on the right is scaled?

The studies are reported on the exponential scale (i.e., RR in this case), as well as the 95%CI; however, the X-axis is somewhat scaled (it is, in fact the distance between 0.1 and 0.5 is not the same as the distance between 0.5 and 1), but I cannot recall what type of scaling (log?) has been done here.

What is the name of this type of X-scale transformation?

Comment: This is a logarithmic axis.

Comment: Log-scaling on the x-axis is not rotationally symmetric.  Values are closer together on the left and farther apart on the right.  In this it looks like it is log-scaled but centered around 1.  This is a good question, and a useful scaling.

Comment: @user89547235 - It smells a little like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale#Extensions or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392853/symmetric-logarithmic-plot-symlog .

Comment: @EngrStudent Those comments are a little baffling, because on a log scale $1$ plays the role of the center.  Thus $10^{-1}=0.1$ and $10 = 10^1$ equidistant and so are $0.5=10^{-0.3}$ and $2=10^{0.3}.$ Moreover, those latter values are 30% of the way along the axis towards the endpoints.  Because, as the OP notes, the risk ratio is a difference in log odds, it is natural to plot these intervals on a log odds scale.

Comment: @whuber - When I think of log-scale, I think of [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b8/Logarithmic_scale.svg/1920px-Logarithmic_scale.svg.png)  The tic's are denser to the left of each interval and are farther apart to the right of each interval, where each interval is a region of consistent inter-tick spacing.

Comment: @EngrStudent This scale corresponds to the left two-thirds of your image.

Comment: @whuber - I think I'm starting to get it.  I think you are saying that for the conventional log10-scale the distance between 0.5 and 1.0 is the same as between 1.0 and 2.0, and that the distance between 0.1 and 1.0 is the same as 1.0 and 10. so the above is almost a traditional log-scale except many of the tick-marks have been hidden?  Because it is a risk-ratio, the risk is balanced at 1.0 so it works as a centerline?

Comment: @EngrStudent That's correct.